# "Order by" clause doesn't work in MySQL query run by Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following query, which works correctly in PHP:

```
SELECT g.*
     , u.username 
  FROM games g
  JOIN users u
    ON g.admin_id = u.id 
 WHERE g.status < 4 
 ORDER 
    BY g.status DESC
     , g.start_date DESC;
```

It returns the rows and orders them correctly by `status desc` and then `start_date desc`.

However, when I try to run the same query from Node.js, it still returns all the rows, but not in the correct order. It seems it orders them by ID, which means it disregards the `order by` clause above. Why is that and how do I fix it? Here is the code:

```
connection.query("    
SELECT g.*
     , u.username 
  FROM games g
  JOIN users u
    ON g.admin_id = u.id 
 WHERE g.status < 4 
 ORDER 
    BY g.status DESC
     , g.start_date DESC;
", function(err, rows, fields) {
        rows.forEach(function(row) {
            //work with each row
        });
    });
```

EDIT: I'm using the [`mysql` package](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql) to connect to MySQL.

Comment: It is most likely an issue with whatever NPM package you are using to connect to MySQL.

Comment: I'm using node-mysql, which I think is pretty standard at this point.

Comment: @jovan For clarification: There's 1) a [`node-mysql` package](https://npmjs.org/package/node-mysql) and 2) a [`mysql` package](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql) with a [`node-mysql` repository](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). Which are you referring to? Because, the latter is probably the more well-established of them.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I'm referring to the one that's installed with `npm install mysql`, as described [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) - so actually the `mysql` package. I didn't even know there were two, I'm pretty new to Node so I just went with someone's recommendation.

Comment: Have you checked `console.log(rows)` before doing further processing, just to be sure?

Comment: Yes, I've done that. It logs them all, but ordered by ID.